# How to fit a HTML table in a flex container body?

Tags: html, css, user-interface, html-table, flexbox

I have the following HTML code and its respective CSS.

The table seems to be spilling out of the main body. How can I extend the body/header to full width and encompass the table and other elements?

I tried width : 100%; and reducing the table and few other tricks but was unsuccessful. In any case, when zoomed into the browser, the table seems to be spilling out nevertheless.

Here is what is looks like at 100% zoom :
[image]

Here is what is looks like when zoomed in:
[image]

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../styles/layout.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../styles/listview.css">
</head>
<body>
    
    <!-- Header Start -->
    <div class = "container container-header">
        <div class = "item item-header-title">
            <h1>TITLE</h1>
        </div>
        <div class = "item item-header-username">
            <h2>
                <a class="item-header-username" href = "#username" target="_blank">
                    @username
                </a>
            </h2>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Header End -->
    
    <div class = "container-page">
        <!-- Sidebar Start -->
        <div class = "container container-sidebar">
            <h4 class = "item item-sidebar">
                <a class ="item-sidebar" href="#home">Home</a>
            </h4>
            <button class="accordion">Page</button>
            <div class="panel">
                <a href= "#" class ="item-sidebar" > - Create new Page</a>
                <a href= "#" class ="item-sidebar" > - Create new Page</a>
                <a class ="item-sidebar" > - View Page</a>
                <a class ="item-sidebar" > - View Page</a>
            </div>  
            <button class="accordion">Page</button>
            <div class="panel">
                <a href= "#" class ="item-sidebar" > - Create new Page</a>
                <a href= "#" class ="item-sidebar" > - Create new Page</a>
                <a class ="item-sidebar" > - View Page</a>
                <a class ="item-sidebar" > - View Page</a>
            </div>
            <h4 class = "item item-sidebar">
                <a class = "item-sidebar" href="#glossary">Glossary</a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <!-- Sidebar End -->
        
        <!-- Content Start -->
        <div class = "container container-content">
            <h1 class = "item item-content item-content-title">
                Title
            </h1>
            <h1 class = "item item-content item-content-body">
                <table id = "listviewTable">
                    <tr>
                        
                        <th>Column</th>
                        <th>Column</th>
                        <th>Column</th>
                        <th>Column</th>
                        <th>Column</th>
                        <th>Column</th>
                        <th>Column</th>
                        <th>Column</th>
                        <th>Column</th>
                        <th>Column</th>
                        <th>Column</th>
                        <th>Column</th>
                        <th>Column</th>     
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Data</td> 
                        <td>Data</td> 
                        <td>Data</td> 
                        <td>Data</td> 
                        <td>Data</td> 
                        <td>Data</td> 
                        <td>Data</td> 
                        <td>Data</td> 
                        <td>Data</td> 
                        <td>Data</td> 
                        <td>Data</td> 
                        <td>Data</td> 
                        <td>Data</td> 
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </h1>
        </div>
        <!-- Content End -->
    </div>
    
    <!-- Footer Start -->
    <div class = "container container-footer">
        <div class = "item item-footer">
            <h1>
                <a class="item-footer" href="Item" target="_blank">
                    Item
                </a> 
                |
                <a class="item-footer" href="Item" target="_blank">
                    Item
                </a>
                |
                <a class="item-footer" href="Item" target="_blank">
                    Item
                </a>
            </h1>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Footer End -->
    <script src="../js/index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    display: flex;
    min-height: 100vh;
    flex-direction: column;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: white;
    width :  100%;
    border: 5px solid rgb(153, 153, 153);
}

.container {
    display: flex; /* or inline-flex */    
    
}

.container-header {
    flex-direction: row;
    /* background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right,rgba(38, 0, 255, 0.9),
    rgba(96, 143, 230, 0.9)); */
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, rgba(34,47,62,0.9),
    rgba(80, 80, 80 , 0.9));
    font-family: "Lucida Console", "Courier New", monospace;
    color: rgba(236,114,17,255);
    /* rgba(236,114,17,255) */
    height: 100px;
    
    align-items: center;
    border: 1px solid rgb(153, 153, 153);
    
}   

.container-page{
    background-color: rgb(233, 24, 24);
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    
}

.container-sidebar {
    background-color: #d7d6d6;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right,rgb(215, 214, 214, 0.9),rgba(104, 101, 104, 0.9));
    flex-direction: column;
    min-height: 100vh;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 25%;
    text-align: left;    
    border: 1px solid rgb(153, 153, 153);
    
}

.container-content {
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 75%;
    border: 1px solid rgb(153, 153, 153);
    font-size: 0.6em;
    font-weight: 10;
    color: #000;
    border: 1px solid rgb(153, 153, 153);
    
}

.container-footer {
    flex-direction: row;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, rgba(34,47,62,0.9),
    rgba(80, 80, 80 , 0.9));
    font-family: "Lucida Console", "Courier New", monospace;
    color: white;
    align-items: center;
    border: 1px solid rgb(153, 153, 153);
    height : 50px;
    font-size : 0.7em;
}

.item {
    /*  */
}

.item-header-title {
    flex-grow: 1;
    text-align: left;
    padding-left: 2%;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    
}

.item-header-username {
    flex-grow: 1; 
    text-align: right;
    padding-right: 2%;
    font-size: 1em;
}

.item-header-title {
    flex-grow: 1;
}

.item-sidebar {
    margin: 0;
    font-weight: 10;
}

.item-content {
    background-color: rgb(150, 243, 167);
}

.item-content-title {
    background-color: rgb(244, 241, 241);
    margin: 0;
    padding: 30px;
    color: #000;
    border: 1px solid rgb(153, 153, 153);
    font-size: 3em;
    
}

.item-content-body {
    background-color: rgb(251, 251, 251);
    flex-grow: 2;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 30px;
    color: #000;
}

.item-footer
{
    flex-grow: 1;   
}

a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}

a.item-sidebar{
    display: block;
    color: #000;
    padding: 20px 16px;
    background-color: #ececec;
}

a.item-sidebar.active {
    background-color: #5a51b6;
    color: white;
}

a.item-sidebar:hover:not(.active) {
    background-color: #5a51b6;
    color: white;
}

.accordion {
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 18px;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    text-align: left;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 15px;
    transition: 0.4s; 
}

.accordion:after {
    content: '\02795'; /* Unicode character for "plus" sign (+) */
    color: #777;
    font-weight: bold;
    float: right;
    margin-left: 5px;
}



.panel {
    padding: 0 28px;
    max-height: 0;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: max-height 0.2s ease-out;
}

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
    align-items: center;
    font-weight: 10;
    font-size: 0.8em;
    
}
 
th, td {
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

Any help or suggestion is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific? What do you want the table to look like?

Comment: It cannot be IMO because the table cell content is hindering the table from shrinking any further. I suggest maybe you can try create a `div.table-container` and put `table#listviewTable` inside it with CSS `.table-container { overflow-x: auto; }`  to allow horizontal overflow with scrolling. https://codepen.io/zeikman/pen/dyqyLym

Comment: @code I have made edits to elaborate my doubts

Comment: @Zeikman thanks for your response, do you mind elaborating the solution you just suggested. I am unable to visualise what you suggested.

Comment: Still, what do you want your table to end up looking like? If it just fits perfectly inside its parent the table would be way to squished to read.

Comment: Here the sample for my suggestion : https://codepen.io/zeikman/pen/dyqyLym

Comment: Thanks @Zeikman, exactly what I was looking for! Will try to implement this.

Comment: @code whatever Zeikman suggested suffices my doubt. Thanks for the discussion anyway!

Answer (score 2):

you should remove the border property from the body selector in the CSS. and add `width: 100%`; to the `.container-header` and `.container-page` selectors and set the `width` of the table to `100%` and remove the `width` property from the `.item-content-body` selector

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: white;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
}

.container-header {
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, rgba(34, 47, 62, 0.9),
    rgba(68, 108, 179, 0.9));
}

.container-page {
  width: 100%;
}

.container-content {
  flex: 1;
  padding: 20px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.item-content-body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
}

th,
td {
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```